# how to add string to PHPUnit failure message universally

Tags: phpunit

I am testing with phpunit and I would like to add the string "**** " to all of the failure message that the developers type in so the message will be easier to identify in the failures.  Now there is the information about which test failed and which assertion failed surrounding the message so you have to work a little harder to find the message - I want to make our messages easier to spot.

I could have the developers just add the string to each message - but that's not very DRY.  Is there a way to universally reformat the failure messages?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will want to modify the `PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter` class.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php

Have a look at the `printDefect...` methods. You should be able to prefix something to the output.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  But I don't want to modify the base class because the next time I have a composer update, I'll lose the changes.  Is there a way to make pass the new functionality into my tests or somehow tell phpunit to use my version of the class?